# Unable to install Firebase App Tester application on Android device with Device Policy profile

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-distribution, google-cloud-identity

Unable to install Firebase **App Tester** application on Android device within work profile - error when uploading APK file through app management of Google Cloud Identity service.

[Secure corporate access on personal devices](https://cloud.google.com/identity/solutions/secure-corp-on-personal-devices) is used in a company.There is a need to install 'App Tester' Android application for [Firebase App Distribution](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/android/set-up-for-testing#download-app-tester). This application does not exist in Google Play. APK is downloaded outside the Play Market by a direct link from Firebase email. Device Policy admin tried to upload APK file as a private app for work profile in Google Cloud Identity service but it does not accept it without any details about the error reason.

Would appreciate any ideas how to use App Tester app on Android device within work profile.

[image]